# How could I get a exception dict information?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

For example:

```
try:
    ...........
    # this exception could be thrown from another method, or just a plain Exception
    raise xxxException({'code': 400, 'error': 'Very common message'})

except xxxException, e:
     ret = {'code':'The code in e', 'error': 'some specific information'}
     raise xxxException(ret)
...........................
```

How could i extract some information from original exception, and add my own information at same time?

Thanks.

Comment: better use except `xxxException as e:`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default the exception argument is stored in the `message` field.
You can get it out with

```
data = e.message
```

and if you want to you can alter it with

```
e.message['bananas'] = 'custard'
```